# Creating a sequential step in a jenkins declarative pipeline preceding a parallel stage

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I would like to setup parallel stages as described in the image

In this instance, the setup is pretty heavy so has to be done once before the parallel group starts of G1, G2 and G3. At the same time, the stage : Initial Checks has 2 items that I would like to run in parallel.

Is this possible in the Declarative Pipeline or do I have to resort to a script?

I couldnt see in the documentation the ability for this to work

```
Stages {
    stage ('P1') {
    }
    stage ('P2 Setup') {}
    stage ('P2') {
    //Here it can contain either Steps or Parallel. I can only do
       parallel {
          stage ('g1') {} //Parallel tests
          stage ('g2') {}
          stage ('g3') {}
       }
    }
    stage ('P2 Cleanup') {}
}
```

Have you encountered similar situations and what have your solutions been like?

Ofcourse 1 solution is to make Setup and Cleanup as part of every group, but like I said, its pretty intensive and I would only take it on if what the diagram indicates isn't possible.

Solution 2

```
 stage ('p2') {
    script {
      //Some scripting here to get the result?

    }
 }
```

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bOdS.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by a DSL or declarative pipeline yet. You are essentially looking for **nested** parallel stages as mentioned [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38442)

Issue is still open with Jenkins community which you can watch [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38442)

In your given case, you can launch stage **P1** and stage **setup** in parallel. However, it is important to start P1 as a background process because from your graph it appears that P1 is a time-intensive operation. Once **group** stage completes, you can collect the status of P1 and proceed to **S2**.

```
stages{
   stage('Build'){
        steps{
              echo "Build"
         }
     }
   stage('Init'){
        parallel{
             stage('P1'){steps{ echo "launch p1 in background"}}
             stage('setup'){steps{echo "setup"}}
           }
     }
   stage('Group'){
        parallel{
             stage('P1'){steps{echo "p1"}}
             stage('P2'){steps{echo "p2"}}
             stage('P3'){steps{echo "p3"}}
           }
     }
   stage('Cleanup'){
        steps{
              echo "cleanup"
         }
     }
   stage('Check P1 status'){
        steps{
              echo "Check"
         }
     }
  stage('S2'){
        steps{
              echo "S2"
         }
     }
}
```

[image: Output will look like thi]

Comment: Thanks for that response. I had a look at the Jenkins items mentioned. The conversation seems to have been going on for quite some time. Will keep following it for updates. Your suggestion works in the interim.

Comment: I wonder if there is any way to have multiple sequential steps in a stage?

If we refer to Ram Kamath's example, can P1/P2/P3 be followed by some other sequential steps before going to "Cleanup"?

Comment: Yes you can have that. I will try to update the pipeline on Monday.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this

```
  node {
        stage("P1"){}
        stage("p2") {}
        stage("p3") {
          parallel (
                "firstTask" : {

                },
                "secondTask" : {

               }
            )
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is not what is asked for. Read the question.